# How to disable DirectAccess for a specific program/website?

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

We are testing DirectAccess and are having issues with a core web application we use called AMS360.

From what I can tell AMS360 uses a .net application as a backend for using the web application, thusly requiring a local installation on the work machines and in addition the required usage of Internet Explorer.

When DirectAccess is `Not Configured`, AMS360 works fine.

When DirectAccess is `Configured and Disabled`, ie the machine is connected locally to the intranet, AMS360 works fine.

When DirectAccess is `Configured and Enabled`, ie the machine is connected to the public internet, AMS360 no longer works.

I have no idea if it is possible, but is it possible to have DirectAccess do nothing when this local application runs and/or when requests are sent to/from this website?

Everything else works fine when DirectAccess is configured, and the machines can access local shares remotely and the "always-on VPN" works, but this key program we use is not compatible nor supported to work with DirectAccess and I'm wondering if there might be a suggested workaround for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Direct access uses the Name Resolution Policy Table to decide as part of its routing process.

If the destination domain related to the AMS360 is associated with a domain name that the NRPT mentions as needing to cross the DA tunnel then it will do so.

So to make exceptions you might need to perform captures to figure out what specific names are used for this application/site.  Then you adjust your DA policies to set bypass exceptions for those domains.

The commands `netsh namespace show effectivepolicy` and `netsh namespace show policy` will let you inspect the policy from your client.

Comment: Thank you this is what I am looking into but have not found a setting that works.  I should also note that with the DCA installed and the GPO to allow the client to `Use local DNS resolution`, using the local DNS resolution allows AMS360 to work.  I will need to look again at the capture.

Comment: I've added all exceptions that I can see for all DNS queries, and still cannot get this site to function properly with DA enabled.  The site connects to https://www.ams360.com, then user logs in, selects a customer, then loads an item from within there.  This should start a local program called `woorkstationcoordinator.exe` which connects to `http://ws.ams360.com`, however when DA is enabled this program fails to load.  I went as far as adding the `/16` netmask for the entire IP block but still no go.